# Adding a redirection link to an AlertController button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, hyperlink, uialertcontroller

(Angular & Ionic)
I would like to add a link to the playstore from my alertcontoller modal. is this possible?

```
    const alert = this.alrtCrtl.create({
      title: `...`,
      subTitle: `...`,
      message: `<div class="image-container"> <img id='...' alt='...' />`,
            buttons: [ {
              cssClass: `cancel-button`,
              text: `X`,
            },
            {
              cssClass: `secure-hub`,
              text: `Go To Play Store`, <<<<<<< this button
            }
          ],
        });
    alert.present();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `handler` to your button that can call the method to open your playstore link:

```
buttons: [ {
    cssClass: `cancel-button`,
    text: `X`,
},
{
    cssClass: `secure-hub`,
    text: `Go To Play Store`, //<<<<<<< this button,
    handler: () => {
        this.yourMethodToOpenUrl()
    }
}
```